# why to use sorting maps on arrays. how is it better in some instances

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn about array sorting. It seems pretty straightforward. But on the mozilla site, I ran across a [section discussing sorting maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) (about three-quarters down the page).

> The compareFunction can be invoked multiple times per element within
>   the array. Depending on the compareFunction's nature, this may yield a
>   high overhead. The more work a compareFunction does and the more
>   elements there are to sort, the wiser it may be to consider using a
>   map for sorting.

The example given is this:

```
// the array to be sorted
var list = ["Delta", "alpha", "CHARLIE", "bravo"];
// temporary holder of position and sort-value
var map = [];
// container for the resulting order
var result = [];

// walk original array to map values and positions
for (var i=0, length = list.length; i < length; i++) {
  map.push({    
    // remember the index within the original array
    index: i, 
    // evaluate the value to sort
    value: list[i].toLowerCase()
  });
}

// sorting the map containing the reduced values
map.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.value > b.value ? 1 : -1;
});

// copy values in right order
for (var i=0, length = map.length; i < length; i++) {
  result.push(list[map[i].index]);
}

// print sorted list
print(result);
```

I don't understand a couple of things. To wit: What does it mean, "The `compareFunction` can be invoked multiple times per element within the array"? Can someone show me an example of that. Secondly, I understand what's being done in the example, but I don't understand the potential "high[er] overhead" of the `compareFunction`. The example shown here seems really straightforward and mapping the array into an object, sorting its value, then putting it back into an array would take much more overhead I'd think at first glance. I understand this is a simple example, and probably not intended for anything else than to show the procedure. But can someone give an example of when it would be lower overhead to map like this? It seems like a lot more work.

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) and [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When sorting a list, an item isn't just compared to one other item, it may need to be compared to several other items. Some of the items may even have to be compared to all other items.

Let's see how many comparisons there actually are when sorting an array:

```
var list = ["Delta", "alpha", "CHARLIE", "bravo", "orch", "worm", "tower"];

var o = [];
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    o.push({
        value: list[i],
        cnt: 0
    });
}

o.sort(function(x, y){
    x.cnt++;
    y.cnt++;
    return x.value == y.value ? 0 : x.value < y.value ? -1 : 1;
});

console.log(o);
```

Result:

```
[
 { value="CHARLIE",  cnt=3},
 { value="Delta",  cnt=3},
 { value="alpha",  cnt=4},
 { value="bravo",  cnt=3},
 { value="orch",  cnt=3},
 { value="tower",  cnt=7},
 { value="worm",  cnt=3}
]
```

(Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/hC6rV/)

As you see, each item was compared to seveal other items. The string `"tower"` even had more comparisons than there are other strings, which means that it was compared to at least one other string at least twice.

If the comparison needs some calculation before the values can be compared (like the `toLowerCase` method in the example), then that calculation will be done several times. By caching the values after that calculation, it will be done only once for each item.

Comment: This is an extremely helpful explanation. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

The primary time saving in that example is gotten by avoiding calls to `toLowerCase()` in the comparison function. The comparison function is called by the sort code each time a pair of elements needs to be compared, so that's a savings of a lot of function calls.  The cost of building and un-building the map is worth it for large arrays.

That the comparison function may be called more than once per element is a natural implication of how sorting works. If only one comparison per element were necessary, it would be a linear-time process.

*edit* — the number of comparisons that'll be made will be roughly proportional to the length of the array times the base-2 log of the length. For a 1000 element array, then, that's proportional to 10,000 comparisons (probably closer to 15,000, depending on the actual sort algorithm).  Saving 20,000 unnecessary function calls is worth the 2000 operations necessary to build and un-build the sort map.

Comment: "The idea is to walk the array once to extract the actual values used for sorting into a temporary array". So the idea is that you could have an array of objects or something multi-dimensional, and you would  just extract the one thing you want to sort and its index, then sort that, then re-attach it to the original array?

Comment: @thomas the idea is to pre-compute (as much as possible) some "distilled" value for each element that makes comparisons *between* elements as cheap as possible.

Answer (score 2):

This is called the “decorate - sort - undecorate” pattern (you can find a nice explanation on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)).

The idea is that a comparison based sort will have to call the comparison function at least `n` times (where `n` is the number of item in the list) as this is the number of comparison you need just to check that the array is already sorted. Usually, the number of comparison will be larger than that (`O(n ln n)` if you are using a good algorithm), and according to the pingeonhole principle, there is at least one value that will be passed twice to the comparison function.

If your comparison function does some expensive processing before comparing the two values, then you can reduce the cost by first doing the expensive part and storing the result for each values (since you know that even in the best scenario you'll have to do that processing). Then, when sorting, you use a cheaper comparison function that only compare those cached outputs.

In this example, the "expensive" part is converting the string to lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

Think of this like caching. It's simply saying that you should not do lots of calculation in the compare function, because you will be calculating the same value over and over.

> What does it mean, "The compareFunction can be invoked multiple times per element within the array"?

It means exactly what it says.  Lets you have three items, A, B and C. They need to be sorted by the result of compare function.  The comparisons might be done like this:

```
compare(A) to compare(B)
compare(A) to compare(C)
compare(B) to compare(C)
```

So here, we have 3 values, but the `compare()` function was executed 6 times.  Using a temporary array to cache things ensures we do a calculation only once per item, and can compare those results.

> Secondly, I understand what's being done in the example, but I don't understand the potential "high[er] overhead" of the compareFunction.

What if `compare()` does a database fetch (comparing the counts of matching rows)? Or a complex math calculation (factorial, recursive fibbinocci, or iteration over a large number of items)  These sorts of things you don't want to do more than once.

I would say most of the time, it's fine to leave really simple/fast calculations inline. Don't over optimize.  But if you need to anything complex or slow in the comparison, you have to be smarter about it.

Answer (score 0):

To respond to your first question, why would the `compareFunction` be called multiple times per element in the array?

Sorting an array almost always requires more than N passes, where N is the size of the array (unless the array is already sorted). Thus, for every element in your array, it may be compared to another element in your array up to N times (bubble sort requires at most N^2 comparisons). The `compareFunction` you provide will be used every time to determine whether two elements are less/equal/greater and thus will be called multiple times per element in the array.

A simple response for you second question, why would there be potentially higher overhead for a `compareFunction`?

Say your `compareFunction` does a lot of unnecessary work while comparing two elements of the array. This can cause sort to be slower, and thus using a compareFunction could potentially cause higher overhead.